# Continuity of $\sin(1/x)$ when $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases} 
> \sin \frac{1}{x} &\text{ if }x \neq 0 \\ 
> 0 &\text{ if } x=0
> \end{cases}
> $$

I have been given this function and told to prove if it's continuous when $x = 0$. Do I need to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$ when $|x| < \delta$?

Comment: Yes, you should use the definition of continuity.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ when $x\ne 0$, and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$? That would be a more standard problem.

Comment: No sorry I just mean sin(1/X) when X does not =0 then 0 when X=0

Comment: You probably are required to *study* if it is continuous, not to show that it is (it isn't).

Comment: What do you call $f(c)$ ??

Comment: Consider studying the limits of both functions separately as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: It is **not** continuous at zero. To see this, choose special sequences (maybe involving $\pi$ ;o)).

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. You can learn to typeset the mathematics by searching for LaTeX or MathJax here on the site. Having nice typeset can help getting answers and also if questions look like they could be homework you are encouraged to show any attempts you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that :

1. A function is continuous at $x_0$ iff whenever $x_n\to x_0$ we have $f(x_n)\to f(0)$.
2. Using the above fact take the sequence $\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\dfrac{2}{\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

the definition of continuity is:$$\lim_{x\to a-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)=f(a)$$

so as 
$x\to 0$ we can see that $\frac{1}{x}{\to \infty}$ as you know whatever be the value of the argument of $sin $ the function is defined (argument must be real) so as x  tends to 0 $\frac{1}{x}{\to \infty}$ but $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ will always oscillate in the range $[-1,+1]$

so when you take left hand limit you will know that $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ does not have a unique value so if no unique value is there no limit exists, no limit exists implies the function is **not** continuous at that point

**NOTE:**

$sin x$ this function is true for all x, whether x is infinity or finite!!